# Is it correct way to return from method with subscription inside (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, subscription, nebular

Is it correct way to return value like in method below?

```ts
  private canView(permission: string, resource: string): boolean {
    let result: boolean;

    this.accessChecker.isGranted(permission, resource)
      .pipe(
        take(1)
      )
      .subscribe(
        granted => {
          result = granted;
        }
      );

    return result;
  }
```

The method is called to set ***show*** property for menu item:

```ts
    @Component({
      selector: 'ngx-pages',
      styleUrls: ['pages.component.scss'],
      template: `
        <ngx-one-column-layout>
          <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </ngx-one-column-layout>
      `,
    })
    export class PagesComponent {
    menu: NbMenuItem[] = [
    {
      title: 'Admin area',
      icon: 'settings-outline',
      show: this.canView('view', 'it_only'),
      children: [
        {
          title: 'config.json',
          link: '/pages/admin-it/config-json',
        },
        {
          title: 'JWT',
          link: '/pages/admin-it/jwt',
        },
      ]
    }]

    constructor(private accessChecker: NbAccessChecker) { }

    private canView(permission: string, resource: string): boolean {
      // see above
    }
```

Can I have a situation when *result* returned before it value will be set in the subscription (for as i know *subcribe* is asynchronous)?
If yes what is the correct way?

Comment: **No**. By the time `return result;` is executed, you do _not_ know if the `result = granted;` has already been executed. So you might return `undefined`. Essentially you cannot return the asynchronous data synchronously. You need to return the observable and subscribe to it where it's emission is needed.

Comment: Can you please show us what "isGranted" function is doing. There could be a possibility that it can execute synchronously.

Comment: @Utkarsh I am using [Nebular](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/security/acl-configuration--usage#acl). [Here](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/master/src/framework/security/directives/is-granted.directive.ts) is source code for "isGranted"

Answer (score 1):

are you using this to create boolean for different `canView` permissions? If so you can just turn those booleans into Observables.

```js
canViewElement1$ = this.canView('element1', 'res1');
canViewElement2$ = this.canView('element2', 'res2');

private canView(permission: string, resource: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.accessChecker.isGranted(permission, resource);
}
```

on the template, if you use it for `ngIf`, call it with async pipe. you won't have to worry about unsubscribing or take(1) this way:

```html
<div *ngIf="canViewElement1$ | async">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not my case. I need to set `hidden` property of menu object and then it renders to template. I've updated my question to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Result might not have the value from the subscription in that point of time

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make `canView` as an `async` function, convert the `Observable` returned by `isGranted` to promise using [`toPromise()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/topromise), then `await` for the result

```
  private async canView(permission: string, resource: string): Promise<boolean> {
    let result: boolean = await this.accessChecker.isGranted(permission, resource)
      .pipe(
        take(1)
      ).toPromise();
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but it gives an error  
`The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type. Did you mean to write 'Promise<boolean>'?`

Comment: @MaksymZapara yes. I missed that out. Edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, I tried this too. And it seems that return value is what is supposed to be (I put `console.log(result)` before return), but when I call the method it says `Type 'Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'`. I've updated my post to make it clear what I try to do.